# Алгоритм поиска пути (туман войны)

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть вводные: точка х - неизвестные координаты, на неизвестной плоскости ( размеры плоскости неизвестны или находятся в пределах 1000 единицы/пикселей). Это отправная точка.
Задача - используя передвижение (кнопки назначены, команды тоже), открыть всю карту. Карта покрыта туманом войны. Сперва была мысль сделать движение по прямой до упора, потом разворот на random(*°). Таким образом, пройдя по точкам разворота, рано или поздно сможем вычислить большую часть точек разворота и узнать карту.
Но, если в середине карты встретиться полость(непроходимая стена), то пиши пропало.

Знает ли кто-нибудь адекватный код для исследования под туманом войны? Или хотя бы ссылки.

Comment: Случайное блуждание? По теореме о случайном блуждании рано или поздно обойдешь всю плоскость)

Comment: @Глеб Да, это так. Но время случайного изучения нереально долгое)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Задача .. открыть всю карту*

Для такой простой задачи достаточно алгоритма Flood Fill ([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заливка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Туман войны в вашем случае на решение никак особо не влияет, т.к. с точки зрения алгоритма, он и так "в темноте и идет наощупь".

Интереснее станет, если вам надо будет оптимизировать перемещения (см. похожую задачу и стратегии её решения - https://youtu.be/ZMQbHMgK2rw?si=LtpdWDYb_Olw90TE&t=338)

> *Но, если в середине карты встретиться полость .. то пиши пропало.*

Наличие большой непроходимой области не должно вас никак расстраивать (если только в задаче нету на этот счет особых указаний. В нее же нельзя попасть, значит и определить, сплошная она или в ней куча рубинов - тоже нельзя.